# Change color scale based on value in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, spatial

I made a spatial plot with color scale from -100 to 100. But the condition is that the value which I plotted have range from -100 to 1500. The result is the values which more than 100 depicted by white region (e.g red arrow).
My question is how can generalized the regions which have value more than 100 to be the same color with the color scale (90-100) dark green.

[image]

Its the script:

```
brks <- seq(-100,100,10)
length(brks)
colorscale <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "BrBG"))(length(brks)-1)
windows()
image.plot(lon,lat,prnew,col=colorscale,breaks=brks,lab.breaks=brks,
           xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
map(database="world", add=TRUE)
# we create customized axes (e.g., labels are added to every 20th degrees)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-180,177.5,20), labels=seq(-180,177.5,20))
axis(side=2, at=seq(-80,80,10), labels=seq(-80,80,10), las=2)

abline(h=seq(-80,80,10), v=seq(-180,177.5,20),lty=2,col="grey",lwd=0.5)
title(main=paste('Relative Bias PR (RCM-EOBS)',SEA[1],'1976-2005',sep=" ")
      ,line=2,cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1.5, cex.main=2, cex.sub=1.5)
mtext("%", side=4, line=2,cex=1.5)
```

If there is anyone who can help me, i can provide you the data to try it on.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand your question, but if you want values higher than 100 to be the same color as 100, you could reclassify these values to 100. Like this

```
# Example dataset      
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:100), value = sample(-100:1500,100))

head(df, n=20)
   ID value
1   1   634
2   2  1151
3   3    69
4   4  1139
5   5   815
6   6   599
7   7  1435
8   8   104
9   9    30
10 10   967
11 11  1205
12 12   244
13 13   932
14 14   890
15 15  1277
16 16  1498
17 17  1094
18 18  1388
19 19    87
20 20   388

# Reclassify values higher than 100 to 100
df$new_value <- ifelse(prnew$value>100, 100, prnew$value) # create a column with the reclassified values

head(df, n=20)
   ID value new_value
1   1   634       100
2   2  1151       100
3   3    69        69
4   4  1139       100
5   5   815       100
6   6   599       100
7   7  1435       100
8   8   104       100
9   9    30        30
10 10   967       100
11 11  1205       100
12 12   244       100
13 13   932       100
14 14   890       100
15 15  1277       100
16 16  1498       100
17 17  1094       100
18 18  1388       100
19 19    87        87
20 20   388       100
```

As you can see I created a column `new_value` where all the values higher than 100 are now 100. You might do the same with your data and I think you should get the desired result when plotting using this new column and the specified breaks.

**EDIT**

Following the OP comment I added a potential solution for `nc` files. You will need `terra`package for this.

```
library(terra)
# This reads the nc file and the variable param 
pr_array <- rast(ncin, subds = 'param')

# Now we can use the classify function in terra to convert all the values above 100 to 100
pr_array_rc <- classify(pr_array, 
                        cbind(100, +Inf, 100),# the cbind indicates that all values from 100 to +Inf should be reclassified to 100
                        include.lowest = TRUE) # include.lowest indicates that 100 should also be reclassified, but it's not really needed in this case.
```

You should then be able to plot using `breaks` just like before, I think.

Comment: Hey thank you for sharing! Yes this is absolutely what i mean. I will try it first. But unfortunately the dataset is not a vector, it is like an nc file (dataframe).

Comment: I use large matrix that produced by ncvar_get() function. `pr_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,varid=param)`
If the condition like this, how can i reclassify the my data?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the nc reclassification. It's hard to tell if this will work without a reproducible example,  but I think it should work.

Comment: Hey thank you! i got this kind of error message . `pr_array_rc <- classify(pr_array[,], cbind(100, +Inf, 100),include.lowest = TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘classify’ for signature ‘"matrix"’`